# Why onChnage is not a function when a functionalities is migrated to a component for better readability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm trying to migrate a specific functionality to a component so I can have better readability in my file.

The functionality is this

```
display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
              const optionValues = preparedSites.reduce((acc, val) => {
                const exists = acc.find(
                  country => country.code === val[3].code,
                );
                if (!exists) acc.push(val[3]);
                return acc;
              }, []);
              return (
                <FormControl>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-chip">
                    Country
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    value={filterList[index]}
                    renderValue={selected => selected.join(' ')}
                    onChange={event => {
                      onChange([event.target.value], index, column);
                    }}
                  >
                    {optionValues.map(item => (
                      <MenuItem key={item.code} value={item.code}>
                        <Flag siteCountry={item} />
                        <ListItemText primary={item.code} />
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              );
            },
```

What I want to get is that

```
display: (filterList, onChange, index, column) => <Compnent filterList={filterList} onChange={onChange} index={index} column={column} />
```

I tried to make it like this but getting onChange is not a function

```
const Component = (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {
    const optionValues = preparedSites.reduce((acc, val) => {
      const exists = acc.find(country => country.code === val[3].code);
      if (!exists) acc.push(val[3]);
      return acc;
    }, []);
    return (
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-chip">Country</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={filterList[index]}
          renderValue={selected => selected.join(' ')}
          onChange={event => {
            onChange([event.target.value], index, column);
          }}
        >
          {optionValues.map(item => (
            <MenuItem key={item.code} value={item.code}>
              <Flag siteCountry={item} />
              <ListItemText primary={item.code} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    );
  };
```

I would like to understand what wrong.

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: It is very difficult to make a working snippets of it. The file containing this is extremely long and complex. I may try but is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to answer my own question as was a simple issue.
Probably do tiring of last pre-Christmas urgency deliveries :(

I forgot to add `{}` in my component:

Before

```
const Component = (filterList, onChange, index, column) => {}
```

After

```
const Component = ({filterList, onChange, index, column}) => {}
```

Now all seems to work correctly.